# An uncertain end for an uncircumcised baby?

Tags: death, brit-milah, gehinnom

According to [this article](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2432015/jewish/Post-mortem-Naming-and-Circumcision-for-a-Stillbirth.htm), a circumcised person cannot enter Gehinnom. It is for this reason that a stillborn baby is circumcised.

So what happens to a stillborn baby that is buried without circumcision?